# how to show file uploader in a floating div?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I want to upload some images and I want to show the file uploader in a floating div 
I should contain 2 button, can u please help me with this.
Please provide me code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [AJAX Modal Popup](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx).

You can watch [[How Do I:] Use the ASP.NET AJAX ModalPopup Extender Control?](http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-modalpopup-extender-control) if you like video tutorials.

Another option would be [jquery popup modal](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/jquery-popup).

Comment: Thanks can we useserver control on it and use it like on facebook floating div for writing message